# Why isn't messageCreate event being fired even though I have all the GatewayIntentBits enabled?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have all the gateway intent bits enabled for my bot, but when a message is sent, the bot isn't logging that any messages are sent using `messageCreate`. I'm using discord.js v14.

```
const token = process.env.TOKEN;
const dataBaseToken = process.env.DBTOKEN;
const { connect } = require("mongoose");
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits, Events } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
  ],
});
client.commands = new Collection();
client.buttons = new Collection();
client.selectMenus = new Collection();
client.commandArray = [];

const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions`);
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
  const functionFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(`./src/functions/${folder}`)
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
  for (const file of functionFiles) {
    if (file.endsWith(".js")) {
      require(`./src/functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
    }
  }
}

client.login(token);
client.handleEvents();
client.handleCommands();
client.handleComponents();
(async () => {
  await connect(dataBaseToken).catch(console.error);
})();

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  console.log(`messageCreate: ${message}`);
});
```

I've tried to use only the neccessary intents, but nothing. I also ran it on a bot with no code, just the basic structure of a bot, and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing immediately jumps out to me when reviewing your code.

Have you tried temporarily giving the bot Administrator privileges? If the `messageCreate` event fires in this scenario, then you can be confident that it indeed is a permissions or intents related issue.

You may also need to give your bot the proper permissions on the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and then generate and re-invite the bot to your server. The permissions page I am referring to will be under OAuth2 for your bot.